# Applying text formatting to CSV file using java

Tags: java, file, csv

```
File temp = new File("C:\\Windows\\Temp\\Sample.csv");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(temp);
try {
    writer.append("Company Name" + ',');
    writer.append("Branch Name" + ',');
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

I am able to create csv file with this code successfully. What I need is I want to apply font color and style to this file content. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: **Bold** formatting should be used sparingly.  Not for entire sentences or paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV file dosen't support formatting. Write to a html or doc file instead.